# Pyplot line with numerical month labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

This must be straightforward, but I've been Googling for an hour and I'm going crazy...

I have a pandas dataframe ("data") with the following layout

```
Month, Value

201101, 5.5

201102, 4.9

201103, 5.1

etc...
```

I simply want to plot a line of the values through the months.

```
pyplot.plot(data["Value"])
```

draws the line, but the x-axis is simply 1,2,3... instead of 201101,201102,201103.

If the axis is interpreted as continuous, 201201 will be very far from 201112, which is not what I want.

What's the trick?

Comment: What data type is in your Month column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your 'Month' data is in `int` format rather than `str`, you simply need to give
`matplotlib` the x values. The function `plot()` takes a minimum of 1 value, in this case it takes this to be the `y` values (in the x, y plot) and creates `x` values `1, 2, 3..` to fit. So you can simply do

```
pyplot.plot(data["Month"], data["Value"])
```

As you will notice however the output is not very pretty, you would be far better converting your dates into datetime objects. Here is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

monthsFmt = DateFormatter("%m '%y")

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(Month = [201101, 201102, 201103, 201104],
                         Value = [5.5, 4.9, 5.1, 6.7]))


datetime_list = [datetime.strptime(str(s), "%Y%m") for s in data['Month']]

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot_date(datetime_list, data["Value"])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
plt.show()
```

A more complete example can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html)